# Render and Saved image look different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, osx, saving

I was trying to render a circle that I would later add glare to in compositing. When I rendered the image with the compositing, it looked fin in blender, however when I saved the image it did not save the glare and it was just a white circle. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Blender     vs     Saved Image
[image]

Compositing
[image]

Comment: did you check compositing in post processing?

Comment: save as OpenEXR, it looks like PNG doesn't correctly save the glare effect over the alpha channel

Comment: ok I will try this

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: make sure that you've enabled transparency for the OpenEXR image when you open it with your software